# R.NET Getting Data from R

Tags: c#, r, parseexception, r.net

I'm trying to make a simple statistical tool with using R and R.NET on C#.NET environment. I'm having problems getting data from R. Code is below

```
bool initResult = REngine.SetDllDirectory(rPackagePath);

if (!initResult)
   throw new Exception(@"R Initialization Failed");

engine = REngine.CreateInstance("tsEngine");

if (engine == null)
   throw new Exception(@"REngine Creation Failed");

engine.Evaluate("testData<-read.table('test_data.txt',sep='', header=TRUE)");
```

I'm trying to get the imported data and show it in a gridview

```
DataFrame dataset = engine.EagerEvaluate("testData").AsDataFrame();
```

I get ParseException at this point.
What can be the problem?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you gotten the [example](http://rdotnet.codeplex.com/) to work or is this your first attempt at R.Net?  As an aside, your syntax looks like it's for an old version.  You should really build from source or install from NuGet and follow the second example from the link above.

Comment: I tried v1.5 but it gives access violation exception with same data :(

Answer (score 1):

First, change the last line to:

```
DataFrame testData = engine.Evaluate("testData<-read.table('test_data.txt',sep='', header=TRUE)").AsDataFrame();
```

Then add the following line:

```
engine.SetSymbol("testData",testData);
```

With the SetSymbol your engine will recognize the variable "testData" if you use it again.